# Natural Isomorphism between Algebraic torus and the Z linear maps from its characters to the field

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory

I'm trying to show the result which is usually noted as 'natural isomorphism' about algebraic tori:
$(\mathbb{C}^*)^n \cong$ $Hom_\mathbb{Z}(M,\mathbb{C}^*)$.

I have defined the map $\theta:$ $(\mathbb{C}^*)^n \to$ $Hom_\mathbb{Z}(M,\mathbb{C}^*)$ by

$\theta(t)=\theta_t:M \to \mathbb{C}^*$

where $\theta_t(m)=\chi^m(t)$, $\chi^m$ being the character $(t_1,\dots,t_n)\to {t_1}^{m_1}\dots {t_n}^{m_n}$. where $m\in M \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$

I believe this to be the correct isomorphism, although it doesnt seen trivial and I am unsure as how to show it is an isomorphism.

Any help would be massively appreciated!
Many thanks

Comment: What is $\chi^m$ exactly? You say "a character", but you should say which one. Also, it seems you are working over $\mathbb{C}$, so actually all tori are split and $M\simeq \mathbb{Z}^n$. If you are working over a different base field you should explain that, and in that case specify what type of morphisms you are considering in $\operatorname{Hom}(M,\mathbb{C}^*)$.

Comment: Thankyou, yes I have made the edit.

Comment: Every homomorphism $\Bbb Z^n\to G$ is determined by where it sends the generators, and if $G$ is abelian they can be sent to any $n$-tuple of elements of $G$. You can determine where all other elements of $\Bbb Z^n$ are sent by writing all other elements as linear combinations of basis elements. So, the isomorphism $\hom(\Bbb Z^n,G)\to G^n$ is **evaluation** at the basis elements, and the map $G^n\to\hom(\Bbb Z^n,G)$ is given by "**linearly extending**" the tuple from (a function from the basis of $\Bbb Z^n$ to $G$) to a (homomorphism from $\Bbb Z^n$ to $G$).

Comment: The two isomorphisms I just described are in fact isomorphisms because they are inverse to each other. The concepts of (a) evaluation and (b) extending functions out of generating sets to homomorphisms are critical to understanding lots of things in abstract algebra. Once these concepts are developed in your intuition, you may get the impression this fact is "trivial."